# Spring security make anonymous user persistent in db and create remember me for them

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need log every anonymous visitor of my chat website into DB with some user data as IP , GEO location etc. 
I would like do this with spring security and if user first time access this website, users credential will be generated into db and I would like to generate for this user some name like guest222 and of course I would like to use for this anonymous user persistent remember me functionality so if user return to my chat site he automatically get his generated name and chat history. Reason why I want use persistent remember me functionality like with authenticated user is more secure than just simple long life cookie. (possibilities detect stolen cookie) 
Could someone advice me where to start to solve this issue? Is possible create some kind of anonymous authentication manager and user remember functionality with it?

I'm using Spring MVC, Spring integration and Spring security.

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html and use a persistent token.

Comment: ok this work fine if I use login form authentication but I need do this without login, in some preuth filter. Exist RememberMeAuthenticationProvider but exist something like RememberMePreAuthProvider?